# No puedo parsear imágenes mediante JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, parsear, img, react-router-dom

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en React y haciendo mi primera página. Parseo información mediante JSON dentro de un componente, y me lee todo el array sin problemas excepto las imágenes. ¿Hay algo en mi código que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Tengo que descargar algo más? Desde ya, gracias.

DatosHamburguesas.json:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name": "Medallones de Soja y Calabaza Veggieland",
        "desc": "4 unidades de hamburguesas congeladas a base de trigo y mandioca con calabaza. Precocido, sin colesterol y vegano.",
        "precio":300,
        "img":"hamburguesa1.jpg", 
        "alt": "Medallones de Soja y Calabaza Veggieland"
    }
]
```

Componente DatosHamburguesas.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ListaHamburguesas from "./DatosHamburguesas.json";

class Listado extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {ListaHamburguesas.Listado.map((elemento, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <h5>{elemento.name}</h5>
              <img src={elemento.img} alt={elemento.alt}/>
              <span>{elemento.desc}</span>
              <p>{elemento.precio}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Listado;
```

[image: Esto es lo que me muestra la página, la imagen está rota]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, compártenos el código como texto. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo gracias por contestar, ahí edité la pregunta.

Comment: Tienes que poner la ruta absoluta de la imagen. Es decir, actualmente en el json `ListaHamburguesas` sólo mandas el nombre del fichero. Tienes que añadir la ruta entera de la ubicación de la imagen `src={"x/y/" +element.img}`. O mandar la ruta entera en el mismo json

Comment: Verifica la ruta donde tienes guardadas las imágenes, que sea la misma que la que te entrega el json

Comment: @hawks lo que sucede es que tengo varios elementos dentro del array, el que puse arriba es un ejemplo. Respondiendo al comentario de Alter Lagos, las imágenes están en la misma carpeta donde tengo el JSON y el .js, por eso me parece raro que no me reconozca la ruta.

Comment: @LourdesMelero, ayudaría si compartes una imágen de la estructura de tu directorio "App", con las carpetas involucradas desplegadas, saludos.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, gracias <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que almacenar tus imágenes en la carpeta `public` de tu proyecto (puedes añadir directorios aquí para no sobrecargarla) ya que no son accesibles de la forma en que lo estás haciendo. Para acceder a ellas simplemente usa la barra `/` antes de la ruta a la imagen.

Por ejemplo:

```
<img src={`/dir1/dir2/${elemento.img}`} alt='...' />
```

Donde `dir1` y `dir2` son posibles subdirectorios dentro de `public` (no hace falta especificar el nombre del directorio `public` como verás en el ejemplo).

Otra solución sería importar las imágenes en el componente donde las vayas a usar, pero al ser dinámicas yo prefiero hacerlo como te explico arriba.

Comment: Me solucionó el problema, te agradezco mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas recomendado es guardar las imagenes en /public pero si deseas guardarlas en /src puedes renderizar las imagenes de la siguiente manera

```
<img src={require(elemento.img)} alt={elemento.alt} />
```

Comment: Hola! Sí, me dijeron lo mismo, al final lo resolví guardándolo en /public. Gracias!